# Up and down keys not working in edit box?

Tags: bug, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I've found that after inserting a hyperlink using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, after that the up and down keys no longer do anything in the edit box. Left and right keys work okay.

I've noticed this in both question and answer edit boxes.

This looks like a bug. Are other people able to reproduce this?

I'm using Firefox 45.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Chrome 49.0.2623.110 on Linux.

Comment: I can reproduce this with Firefox 45 on Linux. The "enter link description here" is selected and I can't move up or down (but left and right works, like described). No errors/messages in the JS console.

Comment: Repro on Windows.  This behavior started about 3 versions ago, give or take.  FF has been pretty flaky lately, looks like they are re-plumbing the basics.  Best to file a bug at Mozilla.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com dupe: [Down arrow key won't work after using the Hyperlink button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264307)

Comment: There is a patch for it as part of [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup)

Comment: I can confirm this on FF 46.0.1 on Windows. Happens with the keyboard shortcut for links (Ctrl-L) as well as clicking the link button in the toolbar.  It's just up and down arrows (not left and right), and this doesn't happen with the image dialog, just the link dialog.